# Why do these 8 bit registers use 16 I/O wires for input and output to the bus? Why not use 8 wires for both input and output?

Tags: cpu

[image]

I'm looking at this diagram from Ben Eater's "[8 bit computer](https://youtu.be/QzWW-CBugZo)" tutorial

What's the need to use separate 8 wires for only data input, and another 8 wires only for data output?

Why not use only 8 wires for both input and output to the bus?

[image]

Comment: That's not a computer science issue, but an [electrical engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) one.

Comment: They all are connected to the same set of 8 wires, both inputs and outputs. As for why the registers themselves need I/O separation, that's indeed an EE question.